# how to convert list<objct> into string []

Tags: java

Is it possible to convert this type `List<Jadval>` into `String[] wordList`?
I read the words from database with like this :

```
public static List<Jadval> jadvalList = new ArrayList<Jadval>();

JadvalDB jadvalDB = new JadvalDB(GameActivity.this);
    jadvalList = jadvalDB.getWords(myPos + 1);
```

and now i want to put `jadvalList` values into `String[] wordList`.
i use this code to set the values :

```
for (int i = 0; i < jadvalList.size(); i++) {
        wordList[i] = (jadvalList.get(i).toString());
    }
```

but I get the error that wordList is empty .
any idea?

Comment: Looks basically right. Where is `wordList` declared? What's the exact error?

Comment: What's `Jadval`?

Comment: Most likely, `jadvalList.size()` is equal to `0`. Did you try printing its value?

Answer (score 3):

You can use streams and complete it in one line like this:

```
String[] wordList = jadvalList.stream().map(a->a.toString()).toArray(String[]::new);
```